# Using workflow rule to check whether record hasn't been touched AND hasn't been shared via Salesforce2Salesforce

Tags: workflow

I have a record that is sometime sent to another connection and the sharing is done manually.  Sometimes the rep forgets to share the record.  Is there a way for me to check via workflow whether the record hasn't been touched in the last 3 days and it does not have a Sent Connection Name?  The latter part is easier, but the former part got me thinking.  It's easier with a formula,  but for some reason formulas can only access the Received Connection Id or the Received Connection Name, but not the Sent Id or Name.  Using conditions gives me access to both.  Is it possible to use a date literal like TODAY()-3 in condition-based workflow rules?